# Finite and Infinite Bases

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

please tell me how $\mathbb{R}^n$ has finite basis ? I understand the polynomial part but not the $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: It means a basis has finitely many elements.

Comment: i do understand that , but how Rn has finite basis ??

Comment: @MohamedOsama: Do you agree that $\mathbb R^2$ has a basis with two elements, for example? Such as $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$.

Comment: Ever consider trying to find a basis for Rn that has more than n vectors? Give it a try.

Comment: yes i do it has dimension = 2

Comment: The definition of $\mathbf R^n$ is the space of lists of $n$ real numbers $(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$, in case this is what needs clarification.

Comment: @MohamedOsama Linear combinations of the vectors with zeros everywhere and a $1$ in the $i^{th}$ coordinate are linearly independent and span all of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: @MohamedOsama: Similarly $\mathbb R^n$ has a basis with $n$ elements for every other $n$ too.

Comment: then why we do not say the basis of polynomials has n elements , and if you read his proof , by the same logic we can say there is always R(n+1) will not be spanned by the basis of Rn

Answer (score 2):

What it says is that *for every $n\ge 0$* the space $\mathbb R^n$ has a finite basis.

There is not a single space called "$\mathbb R^n$" in and of itself -- there is only $\mathbb R$, $\mathbb R^2$, $\mathbb R^3$ and so forth. Speaking about $\mathbb R^n$ is just a way to make the same claim about *each* of these spaces separately.

Comment: why we do not use the same logic for the polynomials as you did for the Rn

Comment: @MohamedOsama: There is _one_ space of _all_ polynomials. That is a completely different situation from $\mathbb R$, $\mathbb R^2$, $\mathbb R^3$ and so forth being _different_ vector spaces.

Comment: so " polynomials " are only like one space but there is no finite basis will contain all of them but in the other hand Rn for every n is in itself a space , although i wonder why discrimination :D why we do not say polynomials of degree 2 are space in themselves.

Comment: Polynomials of degree $\le n$ for any natural number $n$ are a space. But there is also a space of all polynomials, and the book chooses to refer to the latter.

Comment: is it matter of perspective of the author to choose ? he should have pointed that out.

Comment: @MohamedOsama: He's using standard terminology. Saying "$\mathbb R^n$ is finite dimensional" is neither more nor less than saying "Each of  $\mathbb R$, $\mathbb R^2$, $\mathbb R^3$ and so forth is finite dimensional".

Comment: On the other hand, saying something about $P$ is saying something about one particular vector space (and only that), namely the one that consists of all polynomials.